# Problem with Recurrence field in SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar, recurring-events

I want to display the recurrence field in **dataform web part**. But it is getting displayed either 1 or 0.

How do I display the day names here?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the field in Designer and change the datatype to Boolean. This will change the view from 1 or 0 to Yes or No.

Answer (score 1):

Recurrence is a complex field with multiple associated support fields. One of them is the hidden field RecurrenceData that holds the XML schedule.

If you want to extract the days of recurrence you will need to parse it. See [here](http://maiomar.itegyptcorp.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=44) for the schema, as you can see it's not that simple.

There is a iCal Exporter in the [SharePoint Community Kit](http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/4234) on Codeplex.